.net 6: How to get URL without Request Object
I am currently trying to upgrade a logging lib from framework 4.8 to .net 6.
We have the following lines of code
if (isWebApplication)
{
    _URI = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["URL"];
}
else
{
    _URI = My.Computer.Info.OSFullName;
}                       

which I am struggeling to get working again since the System.Web.HttpContext does not exist in this form anymore.
The only way to get the URL is form an existing request object, but since the logging lib should not care if it is  used in a web or desktop app, I cant expect a HttpRequest object.
Are there any other generic ways to solve this?
EDIT: The library is used in this way in multiple applications already which are planned to be updated or EOL in the near of far future, so a rewrite to a less "smart" version is not an option.

If the logging library should be oblivious of its consumers, then, it shouldn't take hard dependencies or make assumptions like above either. Callers should provide this contextual data or inject some object which wraps access to this.

As I said, I am updating this lib to a new .net version. I am not trying to build a new (better) version of it. It should be useable just like the old one.

.NET 6 is .NET Core 6. The singleton HttpContext.Current was one of the very first things removed in ASP.NET Core 1.0. This change is addressed in all docs going back to .NET Core 1.0 and numerous blog posts

@dturnschek you aren't updating to a new .NET version, you're moving to a completely different platform. upgrade a logging lib .NET Core has a built-in logging system used by all libraries. All popular logging libraries like Serilog and NLog already integrate with it. Check for example Serilog's ASP.NET Core integration

Besides, logging the request URL isn't the job of the logging library, it's the job of ASP.NET Core. ASP.NET Core already emits log events for requests including the URL as an attribute, using the ILogger middleware. Log targets like Serilog or the Console write the events to files, the console, Elastic etc based on their configuration. They don't care where that tag came from

But this lib is also used in desktop applications, without middleware such as Winforms. So going all out on a ILogger based approach would result in a completly new lib, which is not m goal.

Forget .NET Core then, because .NET 6 WPF applications also use the .NET Core middleware. .NET 6 WPF apps are .NET Core WPF apps. You don't need a completely new logging library anyway, you need to remove the existing one and let .NET work.

You should check ASP.NET Core HTTP Logging anyway to see how HTTP logging works

this lib is also used in desktop applications all modern logging libraries work on any type of application, with or without integration with ILogger. I use Serilog in web apps, services, console apps and write to files and database tables. In some I integrate with ILogger, in others (mainly console apps) I use Serilog's Logger directly

I have my task and I am supposed to do this. I know that this is not really a good idea, but if you want to argue with my superior, feel free.

@dturnschek your superior can't make the earth flat, the sun rise from the south or change how ASP.NET Core and .NET Core in general works.

You should check the HttpContext here, especially Access HttpContext in ASP.NET Core
